# reading an XML string using LINQ

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, sharepoint, linq-to-xml

I am calling a sharepoint service `/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx` from my silverlight app. In that the method `GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb()` returns the XML string. I need to iterate through that XML string to get the required data. But the LINQ to XML in this scenario is not working, as it is working when loading the XML file and getting the req data. How to do the similar functionality of LINQ to SQL with an XML string?

Sample code:

```
string str = @"<LanguageDetails>
                        <UserNode>
                            <Lang>
                                English
                            </Lang>
                        </UserNode>
                    </LanguageDetails>";
```

Need to handle the similar string and iterate to read the value using LINQ to XML.

Comment: Can you post code showing the results you would like to achieve?  Also, accept answers to your other questions!

Comment: Did you consider using XPath? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument.aspx

Comment: But XPath also expects the xml file to be loaded not the xml string directly Rumpin.

Comment: so create a XmlReader or XmlDocument http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf.aspx This way you are doing the validation too, if the string is in fact XML.

Answer (score 6):

You mean something like this?

```
string str = @"<LanguageDetails>
                   <UserNode>
                       <Lang>
                           English
                       </Lang>
                   </UserNode>
               </LanguageDetails>";
XElement xLanguageDetails = XElement.Parse(str);
foreach (XElement xUserNode in xLanguageDetails.Elements("UserNode"))
{            
}
```

Comment: Ya, but XElement.Load() expects the file path or stream to be passed. Passing str directly wont work alfonso

Comment: My mistake. Use XElement.Parse() instead.

Comment: Its parsing the str fine. But cant able to iterate through it, returning null always for all elements.

Comment: @mhn - Edit your question and post your code so we can take a look.

Comment: If it's returning null for all elements, perhaps there are some xml namespaces involved? What is the actual XML that you want to parse?

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases where you return no rows when doing LINQ to XML queries, the reason is because there is a namespace in your XML. Check the root nodes to see if there are any namespaces and include them in your LINQ queries.